# How can I send mail containing rendered entity from referenced field?

Tags: 7, entities, emails

How do I code a function for sending mail containing a rendered entity that is referenced from a field?

I have content type A that contains static information, and content type B that users create and reference to the corresponding content type A node instead of writing everything manually. In a custom module I have some code for sending mail notifications containing info in a content type B node, but now the client wants some info from the referenced content type A node.

The line of code that I have a problem is this:

```
$avtal_id = $node->field_avtalsnummer['und'][0]['value'];
```

`field_avtalsnummer` is the reference field in content type B that points to a node of type A and `$avtal_id` is used in the mail (plain-text). All other fields in the custom module works fine, but for some reason that I don't fully understand I can't get this to work. If I change `value` to `target_id` i get the node ID but I can't get the value. Title does not work either. Do I need some code to load the entity first? The optimal solution for me would be to get the info from the referenced field and to display a custom view mode so that I can customise the mail notification accordingly to my clients demands, but I can't even get the value of of the referenced field to work so I'm running out of ideas. Help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `target_id` to get the node id, then load the node and get the fields values you want.

```
$avtal_id = $node->field_avtalsnummer[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];
$avtal_node = node_load($avtal_id);
```